# Is it possible to make the Legend shape of Plotly.js always box even in mode line

Tags: javascript, reactjs, plotly

I'm using React with Plotly so this is my code right now

```
<Plot
      data={[
        {
          x: data,
          y: [10, 20, 30],
          fill: 'tozeroy',
          mode: 'none',
          marker: {
            color: 'red',
          },
          name: 'Legend 1',
        },
        { mode: 'lines', x: data, y: data1, name: 'Legend 2' },
      ]}
    ...
    />
```

I can render it already but the shape of the legend will be a line.

Is there a possibility to change the shape of the legend to like box in Bar mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible at present. The legend is handled by Layout and having looked through the [documentation](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/#layout-showlegend) there is nothing about symbol choice.

Sorry I can't be of more help.